# MakeHuman is destorting my MakeClothes clothing (Blender)

Tags: makehuman

I'm trying to make clothes in Blender with MakeClothes.

I've added the model "Female Average With Help". I've selected tights as the object to change and have scaled it up. All I wish to export is the top. 
[image]

When I press "Make clothes" it doesn't wrap around the model correctly...
[image]
I don't understand the warning I get in the image above. I don't think it has anything to do with the problem though... 
Anyway I go to MakeHuman. I can import my top but as you can see, it has problems. Make human has added additional geometry to the model.
[image]

I follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eskfzfU4NsI

Comment: Have you solved the problem? We have made many clothes without problem but with the last Makeclothes and Makehuman (1.1.0) we start to have the same triangle distortion like you have. :/