# Makeclothe->Makehuman tr

Tags: makehuman

Our designer creates clothes for Makehuman, using Blender+Makeclothes.

A few weeks ago we updated to Makehuman 1.1.0, and also MakeClothes and find a problem: in many upper part (eg tee shirts) the export from MakeClothes is OK (no error) but while opening in MakeHuman, the border of the clothes (especilly necks) has very big triangle distortion.

If we import these clothes in the older version of MakeHumain, everythings' OK.

Have you heard about that and do you have any idea to solve?

Note: I've found a king of similar question:
[MakeHuman is destorting my MakeClothes clothing (Blender)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41368/makehuman-is-destorting-my-makeclothes-clothing-blender)
But with no reply...

Answer (score 2):

We've find explanation about this strange effect.
If we open the file in an old blender version (before 2.77), export it using "old makeclothes" into "old makehuman" (1.0); everything's OK.
If we update Makeclothe we have strange triangles at neck level and if we update makeclothes, we loose texture (file not found).

In order to solve that:
1) update everything (Blender, Makeclothes and MakeHuman)
2) open a new project in Blender
3) Append the clothes in Blender (so don't "Open" but "Append")
4) Export using Makeclothes
5) Open in MakeHuman 1.1.0
And everything's OK!